# Elasticsearch - Filter => Bool => Should(delegate array) - want automation, not hardcoded, how?

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch 8.1.2 (Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch) in C#

Filter => Bool => Should can take a comma separated list of lambda expressions as evident in the framework.  The call to Should in my current code is about 2/3 way down in the ful code below.  The argument used to get the Field and Query is a List(Field, string) named p_should_contain.  This can have a dynamic size.

If I iterate over the list, and set up a Should condition, Should gets overwritten by the current iteration and only the last iteration Should value is used as evident by the DebugInfo.

Should has an overload of `Action<QueryDescriptor<T>>[]`

However, when I create an array of delegates, runtime results in an error where the delegate values passed to Should are null.  Here is how I am attempting to do that:

```
    Action<QueryDescriptor<T>>[] z = new Action<QueryDescriptor<T>>[p_should_contain.Count];
    boolQuery.Filter(f =>
      f.Bool(b => b.Should(s =>
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < p_should_contain.Count; ++i)
        {
              Action<QueryDescriptor<T>> u = s => s.Match(m => m.Field(p_should_contain[i].Item1).Query(p_should_contain[i].Item2));
              z[i] = u; 
        }
      })));
    
    boolQuery.Filter(f => f.Bool(b => b.Should(z)));
```

Here is the complete function with a comma separated hardcoded Should setup about 2/3 way down.  How can I get this dynamically set up?  Apologize for the crap formatting

```
    public async Task<List<T>?> SearchAsync<T>(
         string p_index_to_search,
         string p_search_term,
         string? p_collapse_property_name,
         Field[] p_should_fields,
         Dictionary<Field, string>? p_must_contain = null,
         List<(Field, string)>? p_should_contain = null
         ) where T : class
    {
        // check the index passed in to determine what index to use

        SearchResponse<T> response = null;

        response = await _client.SearchAsync<T>(search =>
        {
            search.Index(p_index_to_search)
                   .Query(q => q
                       .Bool(boolQuery =>
                       {
                           if (p_must_contain is not null)
                           {
                               foreach (var field in p_must_contain)
                               {
                                   //Add all fields that must match
                                   //if must fields is null nothing will be added
                                   boolQuery.Must(mustQuery => mustQuery
                                               .Match(match => match
                                                   .Field(field.Key)
                                                   .Query(field.Value)
                                               )
                                           );
                               }
                           }
                           
                           
                           // the search match
                           boolQuery.Should(shouldQuery => shouldQuery
                                        .MultiMatch(multiMatch => multiMatch
                                            .Query(p_search_term)
                                            .Fields(p_should_fields)
                                            .Type(Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.QueryDsl.TextQueryType.MostFields)
                                            .MinimumShouldMatch(1)
                                        )
                                    );


                           boolQuery.Filter(f =>
                                        f.Bool(b => b.Should(
                                            s => s.Match(m => m.Field(p_should_contain[0].Item1).Query(p_should_contain[0].Item2)), 
                                            s => s.Match(m => m.Field(p_should_contain[1].Item1).Query(p_should_contain[1].Item2))
                                            )));
            .Size(20)
            .Explain();


            //Only perform a collapse on the search object if a collapse property name is passed in
            if (p_collapse_property_name is not null || p_collapse_property_name?.Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                search.Collapse(o => o.Field(new Field(p_collapse_property_name)));
            }
        });

        if (response.IsValidResponse)
        {
            return response.Documents.ToList();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I have tried what I have mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using what you'd already built I was able to slightly modify and make this work.

**Building the Action<QueryDescriptor>[] array:**

```
    Action<QueryDescriptor<T>>[] actions = new Action<QueryDescriptor<T>>[p_should_contain.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < p_should_contain.Count; i++)
    {
        var (fieldName, queryText) = p_should_contain[i];
        actions[i] = q => q.Match(m => m.Field(fieldName).Query(queryText));
    }
```

**Using the array in a boolQuery Filter:**

```
    if (p_should_contain is not null)
    {
       boolQuery.Filter(filter =>
       {
          filter.Bool(b => b
                   .Should(actions)
                   .MinimumShouldMatch(1)
          );
       });
     }
```

**Produces this query:**

```
    "query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [{
                        "match": {
                            "fieldNameToSearch": {
                                "query": "some value"
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        "match": {
                            "fieldNameToSearch": {
                                "query": "some other value"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "minimum_should_match": 1
            }
        },
```

**Explaining the issue:**
Lambda expressions capture references to variables, not the variables current value. So when the value of `i` changes, each lambda expression grabs the current value of `i`.

The last loop bumps `i` to 2 and terminates. However, `i` is now 2 at this point and the lambda references, while you expect them to be 0, 1 will instead be 2,2 which are out of bounds for both expressions that were built.

My implementation avoids this by creating the local variables `var (fieldName, queryText)` so each lambda has a reference to its own local variables.

Comment: I believe I understand.  Because we are storing delegates from within a loop and it is deferred execution, the iterator i becomes 2 and the for loop is done.  Because i was last known as 2, the deferred delegate is trying to access its last known value.  To do this correclty, we needed to create a memory address for the tuple values and store them for use within the delegates.